# Send a different version to CC recipient

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I would like to add text to a C# generated email just to the ones that were CC'd. I would like to add the text "You Were Courtesy Copied In This Email, No Action Is Required By You" to the top of any email I generate.

I use the System.Net.Mail.AlternateView, is there something like a CCView? I'm tasked to do this by my CEO, so please don't ask "why would I want to do this"! He doesn't have time to read the TO fields or CC fields to make the determination. I know, I know.

Comment: Here is where I extract the CC, maybe can add to the body just for these people?  `string[] emailCC = cc.Split(";".ToCharArray());
            if (emailCC.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string itemCC in emailCC)
                {
                    if (isValidEmail(itemCC))
                        mailMsg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(itemCC));
                }
            }`

Comment: This just isn't how email works. Email servers that distribute the mail take the addresses and distribute the same body copy to everyone. The only way to accomplish this is to send a separate email to the CC: recipients.

Comment: `CC` means `Carbon Copy`, it can't be different, so need to send different mail to CC persons, and make them CC only in 2nd mail.

Comment: Why doesn't your CEO simply create an inbox rule to move all messages he is cc'd to a dedicated "no action" folder? Or rather have somebody create it for him ... *"Sure thing Mr. Denholm, Sir - will be done in 6 to 8 weeks."*

Comment: Your comments are obvious, I know the definitions, but dare not say impossible. There is always a way. The CC rule is interesting, I would have to also tag the FROM so as not to mess with his other outside emails.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add text to a C# generated email just to the ones that were CC'd.

Can't be done.  It's not a C# problem, it's just the fundamental design of email.  One message, many recipients.  If you want to have a different message, it's a different email.  Something like:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
var directMail = new MailMessage();
var copyMail = new MailMessage();

// set the properties on both

client.Send(directMail);
client.Send(copyMail);
```

For the "CC" one (`copyMail`) you may need to supply some dummy address in the "To" field.

Comment: thank you for offering suggestions instead of just slamming me for asking this question!

Comment: I like the concept here, but then he wouldn't know who it was intended for (nobody in the TO field) and its not "TO" him. I think it may be a catch 25 (play on catch 22, but SMTP port, bahahaha!)

Comment: @AdamRoof: In that case the question really comes back to the requirements.  What *does* he want?  If he's looking for a way for his email client to treat messages differently depending on those messages, that would be a matter for the client.  If he wants the messages themselves to *be* different, that's a matter for the sender (in this case the code).

Comment: he, at this point, asked for the messages to be different. Im just not giving up on the impossible yet. A point was made above to have him use Outlook rules, and that may be the way we have to go. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamRoof: You're probably right.  He's not the first executive to try to dictate a technical solution that doesn't make sense, instead of just articulating the actual problem he's facing and allow his team members to derive a viable solution :)